# XML query data in columns

Tags: xml, plsql, extract

I have an xml made like this: I would like to extract the values in a way each field between the main tag `<queue></queues>` shows in a row.
I have found many example of how to do a "select extract" but nothing like my xml (where each fields is not called - ie - "value" but value so I just do not know how to read them.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<queues>
    <queue>
        <Field name="queue_date">2016-09-20</Field>
        <Field name="queue_id">6180</Field>
        <Field name="queue_activate_time"/>
        <Field name="queue_deactivate_time"/>
        <Field name="provider_id">19</Field>
        <Field name="provider_source">Nome Cognome</Field>
        <Field name="provider_ext_id">ncognome</Field>
        <Field name="provider_pool">18</Field>
        <Field name="provider_timezone">Central Europe</Field>
        <Field name="calendar_start_time">08:00:00</Field>
        <Field name="calendar_end_time">17:00:00</Field>
    </queue>
</queues>
```

Comment: in my last explanation row, I meant: XMLs examples found refere as a field name="value name"-value structure (my xml) against a value_name--value structure (what I was able to find)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from xmltable('//queues/queue/Field' passing xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<queues>
    <queue>
        <Field name="queue_date">2016-09-20</Field>
        <Field name="queue_id">6180</Field>
        <Field name="queue_activate_time"/>
        <Field name="queue_deactivate_time"/>
        <Field name="provider_id">19</Field>
        <Field name="provider_source">Nome Cognome</Field>
        <Field name="provider_ext_id">ncognome</Field>
        <Field name="provider_pool">18</Field>
        <Field name="provider_timezone">Central Europe</Field>
        <Field name="calendar_start_time">08:00:00</Field>
        <Field name="calendar_end_time">17:00:00</Field>
    </queue>
</queues> ')
columns 
   name varchar2(100) path './@name'
 , value varchar2(100) path'./text()'

)
```

Comment: This works! But what is my XML is contained in a XML Table I created in Oracle? It stays in a CLOB field.

Comment: `select ... from your_table, xmltype('...' passing xmltype(your_clob_column) .....) `